# Error when compiling nettle-2.7.1

Tags: gmp, gnutls

When I try to compile nettle-2.7.1, I get the following:

root@tcx2270-19:~/nettle-2.7.1# make
make: Warning: Can't find `aes-decrypt-internal.o.d': No such file or directory
make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 594: Read of include file`aes-decrypt-internal.o.d' failed

Has anyone seen this issue?  Thanks.

Comment: What does this have to do with GMP?

Comment: Because the nettle library is dependent on the GMP library.

Comment: I don't recall seeing any AES stuff in GMP. Maybe it's complaining about another dependency.

Comment: I don't think it's complaining about the GMP library either, but I tagged GMP just in case.

Comment: By the way, I see "aes-decrypt-internal.c.o.d" in the directory.  And it's complaining about missing "aes-decrypt-internal.o.d".  So the different in the name is the ".c".  Could it be something to do with the Makefile?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the exact same problem. It has nothing to do with gmp. The ./configure script generates a broken Makefile. After doing some analyzation of the generated Makefile I figured out a solution.

On the very bottom of the generated **Makefile** search for the line that looks like the following:

```
DEP_FILES = $(SOURCES:.c=.$(OBJEXT).d) $(SOURCES:.c=.p$(OBJEXT).d) asm.d
```

You can fix the build by changing it to the following line:

```
DEP_FILES = $(SOURCES:.c=.c.$(OBJEXT).d) $(SOURCES:.c=.c.p$(OBJEXT).d) asm.d
```

---

Additionally, we have to fix the Makefiles in all sub-directories.

For **./tools/Makefile**, on the very bottom, find the line that looks like:

```
include  $(SOURCES:.c=.$(OBJEXT).d)
```

and change it to

```
include  $(SOURCES:.c=.c.$(OBJEXT).d)
```

Furthermore, you need to add the following two build-targets:

```
../libnettle.a:
        $(MAKE) -C .. libnettle.a

../libhogweed.a:
        $(MAKE) -C .. libhogweed.a
```

---

For **./testsuite/Makefile**, on the very bottom, find the line that looks like this:

```
DEP_FILES = $(SOURCES:.c=.$(OBJEXT).d) $(CXX_SOURCES:.cxx=.$(OBJEXT).d)
```

and change it to:

```
DEP_FILES = $(SOURCES:.c=.c.$(OBJEXT).d) $(CXX_SOURCES:.cxx=.cxx.$(OBJEXT).d)
```

---

Finally, in **./examples/Makefile**, again on the very bottom, search for the line that looks like:

```
include  $(SOURCES:.c=.$(OBJEXT).d)
```

and change it to

```
include  $(SOURCES:.c=.c.$(OBJEXT).d)
```

Phew, at least for me, that makes the build work. Of course, this is an ugly solution but it gets the job done. A better solution would be to fix the configure-script but I did not have the time to do it yet. It is also worth noting that nettle 3.0 does not have this issue. Too bad gnutls does not work with that newer version.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: I created a patch which does all the above fixes in the Makefile.in files. As a result, you don't have to fix them yourselfs. Optimally, just unpack the source, apply the patch and proceed the way you normally would by continuing with the ./configure.

Get it from here: http://pastebin.com/36M5LHK3